# How can I retrieve the state of my BITS Job?

Tags: c#, file-transfer, microsoft-bits

i am using the Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Messaging package to use the BITS.
So far I have written following piece of code:

```
BitsJob job = new BitsJob(BitsJobType.Download, displayName);
BitsJobState jobState;
job.AddFileToJob(new Uri(source), destination); // source & destination are method parameters
job.Resume();
do
{
    // Do something with the job as long as its transferring
} while (/*Get job state here*/);
```

Now I want to retrieve the state of the job in the do-while-statement. I can't find a property or a method of the `BitsJob` instance returning me the current state of the job. Can someone tell me about how to get the current job state?

Comment: Would that be because this class was designed to tell, not be asked, and has an *event* for the purpose of discovering progress?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes you´re right I figured it out too. I just posted a working code piece in case that somebody has the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer by myself. For all those who hang around with this question. The best way is to retrieve it using the `BitsJobProgress` event. Following code sample can show that

```
Job.BitsJobProgress += (sender, e) => 
{
    JobState = e.JobState;
};
```

The `BitsJobEventArgs` include the job state. That way its possible to retrieve it and save it in a variable.